# Does a continuous deformable mirror cause diffuse reflection?

Tags: exoplanet, mirror, adaptive-optics

We have all seen images like this of deformable mirrors:

[image]

Continuous deformable mirrors are known to have a higher [quality](https://www.rp-photonics.com/deformable_mirrors.html) over segmented mirrors, but it seems to me that a continuous mirror (or even a segmented tip tilt mirror) would cause diffuse reflection.  Here is a figure showing a segmented and a continuous mirror

[image]

Since the light is coming in normal to the telescope (let's just say space telescope so we can avoid all possible atmospheric non-normal light), the purpose of the deformable mirror is to adjust the **phase** of the light.  It would appear to me that a continuous deformable mirror would also diffuse the light as seen from my rough drawing (I know that most mirrors are placed at a 45 degree angle, but you get my point).  Here is a figure showing the diffuse reflection at a 45 degree angle.

[image]

It is well known that a segmented mirror causes light scatter (at each segmentation location), but I have not been able to find any literature on light diffusion on a continuous deformable mirror.  This must be true, but how is it not a problem and how do they address it? (pointing towards scholarly resources would be appreciated)

**UPDATE**

I will accept the answer posted below, but I think it is missing something important.  In the fourth bullet it is stated,

> I would conjure that the diffusion reflection at segmentation locations is not significant enough compared to the overall sub-mirror reflection

This is still an opinion (though it could be correct), which is why I specifically asked for scholarly resources.

I reached out to Professor Thomas Bifano from Boston University who specializes in deformable mirrors and his answer made sense and was readily verified in scholarly [papers](http://www.graphics.cornell.edu/%7Ewestin/pubs/TorranceSparrowJOSA1967.pdf)

> Diffuse reflection occurs when the reflective surface is rough: scale of surface asperities is large in comparison to the wavelength of light reflecting from it. In diffuse reflection, incident light at a fixed angle of incidence reflects (actually, scatters) at many different angles. If the local roughness of the surface is <<wavelength, there no diffuse reflection.

Comment: I'm not sure that you have the same understanding of "scatter" as how it's used in optics. Scattering is when there are rays going different directions from the same point, but I get the impression that you are using it to mean different directions from different points.

Comment: @Acccumulation Yes you are correct if you are discussing a single photon. If you are describing a wavefront, then scattering is still appropriate.  Since I mixed the two together without a clear distinction, I updated my question.

Comment: (1) If you look at any mirrors at home, you may find litter diffuse reflections -- that said, mirrors are highly specular, not to mention crafted high-performance deformable mirrors for adaptive optics. (2) The AO diagram shown at 45 deg is for visualization purposes -- in reality the incoming beam is impinging almost perpendicular to the deformable mirror, and this makes the mirror more specular. Given (1)(2), I do not think your statements hold.

Comment: @WDC To address both of your points, 1) yes it is a mirror so it is specular (it will reflect at the same angle from the normal); however, since it is deformable, the normal changes meaning that the wavefront will diffuse.  2) it doesn't matter if it is at a 45 degree or normal to the mirror, if the localized normal is not consistent, then it will cause diffuse reflection.  Also, you said it is "more specular", yes I agree that the majority of the wavefront will have the same refection, but diffuse reflection will occur because of the deformable mirror, so how do they minimize it?

Comment: @Josh Okay I understand the issue here. Please see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your reply it seems your definition of diffusion is slightly different from my sense. But the phenomenon is true that at segmentation locations wavefronts are being deflected not in a uniform manner, causing the diffusion issue posted in this question.

Before addressing this issue, let me briefly describe how adaptive optics works in practice. In a typical AO system, a wavefront sensor measures the incoming wavefront distortion (usually it's slopes), given which a deformable mirror corrects for. The deformable mirrors consist of multiple actuators, which enable the mirror deformation. These actuators are controlled by commands.

The input/output are:

- Input: wavefront slopes $\mathbf{y}$
- Output: actuator control commands $\mathbf{x}$

These two are usually related through a so-called interaction matrix $\mathbf{A}$:
$$
\mathbf{y} = \mathbf{Ax}
$$
This matrix models all system artifacts, including the diffusion issue in this question. Since we would like to solve $\mathbf{x}$ from $\mathbf{y}$, we would also like the pesudo-inverse of $\mathbf{A}$, denoted as $\mathbf{A}^{-1}$, so in real-time the AO system can solve the actual commands as:
$$
\mathbf{x} = \mathbf{A}^{-1} \mathbf{y}
$$
$\mathbf{A}$ and $\mathbf{A}^{-1}$ are usually calibrated before running the AO system.

Now consider this question:

- Yes, there are diffusion reflection from the mirror. But this issue contributes in part to the interaction matrix $\mathbf{A}$. As long as people calibrate it carefully it does not really affect AO performance.
- For normal AO systems both measurement and correction wavefront lateral resolutions are low: typically at thousands of measurements, i.e. $\mathbf{x}\in\mathbb{R}^{1000}$ or so. In such a situation, I would conjure that the diffusion reflection at segmentation locations is not significant enough compared to the overall sub-mirror reflection, i.e. the fill factor of the sub-mirror is high enough to ignore this effect.